# How to return minimum date from an xml set using Xquery

Tags: xml, date, xquery, minimum

I want to return minimum date(2020-11-21) from above xml using Xquery. I tried below.

Query:

let $PED :=
for $pi in //abc
let $dates:=min(xs:date(substring(($pi/regdate),1,10)))
return {$dates}
return $PED)

Result : 
2020-11-21
2021-11-21

Expected Output : 2020-11-21

Comment: Input XML:

<main>
<abc>
<regdate>2020-11-21-05:00</regdate>
</abc>
<abc>
<regdate>2021-11-21-05:00</regdate>
</abc>
</main>

Answer (score 0):

Compute a sequence of `xs:date` values from your XML input and then apply the `min` function to that sequence:

```
let $dates := <main> <abc> <regdate>2020-11-21-05:00</regdate> </abc> <abc> <regdate>2021-11-21-05:00</regdate> </abc> </main>
//regdate/xs:date(substring(., 1, 10))
return min($dates)
```